# distributional derivative of $x^{-1/2}$.

Tags: distribution-theory

Consider the distribution defined for $\phi \in C_{c}(\mathbb{R})$ by $$T(\phi) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |x|^{-1/2} \phi(x) dx.$$ Compute its derivative $T^{\prime}(\phi)$.

Attempt: I use $(T^{\prime}, \phi) = -(T, \phi^{\prime})$. How to remove its dominant singularity? I think the answer should be $-\frac{1}{2} |x|^{-3/2} + $ some terms...

Comment: Do you mean $C_c^\infty$? Otherwise the definition you provide doesn't necessarily make sense.

Comment: That's what given by the problem...

Comment: Does it say in what form you have to compute it? Because in a way $-(T, \phi')$ is the correct answer...

Answer (score 2):

Note that $\dfrac{d}{dx} |x|^{-1/2} = - \text{sgn}(x) |x|^{-3/2}/2$ (where sgn is the signum function), not $- |x|^{-3/2}/2$.

$T'(\phi)$ is the [Cauchy principal value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value) of $- \displaystyle\frac{1}{2} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \text{sgn}(x) |x|^{-3/2} \phi(x)\; dx$

Comment: Can you elaborate more on your answer?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Break the integral into two parts - from $0\to\infty$ and $-\infty\to 0$.